# Why am I getting a NullPointerException even through a check?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestSlot.isInternetExplorerAvailable(TestSlot.java:274)
    at WebProxyHtmlRendererBeta.getSingleSlotHtml(WebProxyHtmlRendererBeta.java:168)
    // the rest is irrelevant
```

**TestSlot#isInternetExplorerAvailable()**

```
public Boolean isInternetExplorerAvailable() {
  if (currentSession.get("isInternetExplorerAvailable") != null) // line 274
      return (Boolean) currentSession.get("isInternetExplorerAvailable");
    return false;
  }
```

`currentSession.get(String key)` is a simple fetcher to fetch from a `HashMap<String,Object>`

**...getSingleSlotHtml()**

```
else if (browserName.contains(BrowserType.IE) || browserName.contains(BrowserType.IEXPLORE))
      if (!s.isInternetExplorerAvailable()) { // line 168
        htmlClass += "browserNotAvailable ";
        imgSrc = imgSrc.split(".png")[0].concat("_unavailable.png");
        title = "browser not available";
      } else { htmlClass += "browserAvailable "; }
```

The questionable thing is, is that I tested this same type of logic using this SCCEE:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        settings.put("something", true);

        if (settings.get("something_else") != null)
            System.out.println("it's not null");
        else
            System.out.println("it's null");
    }
}
```

And it put out `"it's null"` which means that I can do that null check using the `!=`.  Any ideas why this wouldn't be working for me in the `TestSlot#isInternetExplorerAvailable`method?

Comment: @Keppil has it correct, if currentSession was null, you would get a null pointer exception when trying to call currentSession.get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way the line

```
if (currentSession.get("isInternetExplorerAvailable") != null) // line 274
```

throws an `NullPointerException` is if `currentSession` is null. Add a check for that first:

```
if (currentSession != null && currentSession.get("isInternetExplorerAvailable") != null) // line 274
```

Comment: For those not used to it, the if (currentSession != null && currentSession.get()     line will not bomb out because the logic is shortcutted.  Basically the program looks at the first part of the expression, and if it is false it never evaluates the second part.  This is not true in all languages, however.

Comment: further reading the documentation of the project: `@return the session. Null if the slot is not used at the moment.`  looks like it IS in fact returning `null`.  so obvious.  gah. will accept in 6 mins

Answer (score 1):

Your 'currentSession' variable in line 274 is null.
Exception occurs when you try to call 'get' on null.

Try

```
if(comparing 'currentSession != null && currentSession.get("isInternetExplorerAvailable") != null) { ......}
```